# How to make two lists, one with even numbers and one with odd numbers, in scheme?

Tags: scheme

I have a problem.

For example:

We have one unsorted list:

```
(1 4 5 3 6 7)
```

Can you help me make **2 lists**?

One **odd numbered**, increasing list:

```
(1 3 5 7)
```

and the other **even numbered**, decreasing list:

```
(6 4)
```

Don't use sort!

Comment: a. what have you tried? b. (4 6) is increasing, not decreasing.

Comment: can you make one list, of evens in decreasing order, from an argument unsorted list? start with this task. show us your code. :) (and no, I didn't downvote you, but whoever did were in their right because you really should show some code here on SO, or else it's a *bad* question, and it gets closed, and if you do this a lot you get *banned* from asking.... beware! :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define (split filter lst)
  (let loop ((a '()) (b  '()) (lst lst))
    (if (null? lst)
        (values a b)
        (let ((cur (car lst)))
          (if (filter cur)
              (loop (cons cur a) b (cdr lst))
              (loop a (cons cur b) (cdr lst)))))))

(split odd? '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
; ==> (9 7 5 3 1), (10 8 6 4 2)
```

Now, to make one that separates odds from evens and in a specific order would be simple.